# Rails create join table index name is too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to create a join table between the tables `users` and `looking_for_options`.

This is my migration file:

```
class CreateJoinTableOptionsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :looking_for_options, :users do |t|
      t.index [:looking_for_option_id, :user_id]
      t.index [:user_id, :looking_for_option_id]
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Index name 'index_looking_for_options_users_on_looking_for_option_id_and_user_id' on table 'looking_for_options_users' is too long; the lim
>   it is 64 characters

Knowing that for a `join table`, `rails` convention is `Table_A_Name_Table_B_Name`  and its columns follow a similar convention `Table_A_id` and `Table_B_id`.

How do I specify a shorter column name for the `joint table` so it doesn't break `rails` many-to-many associations?

**Update:**

I found that I can give just the index a different name instead. But will `rails`'s many-to-many association actually utilize it?

```
class CreateJoinTableOptionsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :looking_for_options, :users do |t|
      t.index [:looking_for_option_id, :user_id], name: 'option_user'
      t.index [:user_id, :looking_for_option_id], name: 'user_option'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... will rails's many-to-many association actually utilize it?

The choice of whether to use the index or not is made by the database optimiser, and is not affected by Rails. You can name it what you like, within the constraints imposed by the database.